# How to set field values in a 'create form' by using dialog?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to update an activity entity's create form's fields by using a dialog without saving the entity first?

Let me explain.

The customer calls us and our represent opens a phone call activity. At this point it's on a 'create new' state.

Now, since we have freaking many contact informations and other things related to it in the system I have created a dialog to help user to find out the caller's informations. The dialog first asks the name who is calling. Then it asks about which building / apartment he is calling (it's part of our business model). Then it keeps asking things for a while.

Finally, the dialog has gathered all necessary information and is about the put the values into the form.

But here's the thing. I'm using an Update process within the dialog, but of course I can't update something that doesn't exists.  So at the moment it works like we always have to save and give a title for the entity first. Then run the dialog.

It's a minor fault but it may be a problem if, for some reason, in the middle of a dialog, the process is cancelled. Then we would have an empty phone call there with some title. Besides one extra click is always one extra click.

I hope you understood my question.

Please feel free to asks.

Bye!

Answer (score 1):

Like Greg, it seems to me that you are trying to capture information about the contact and the phone call at the same time, so starting by opening a new record may not be the most structured way to go about this. A couple of possibilities:

- use a dialog but don't run it against a Contact necessarily. Maybe run it against a user. Use the first few pages to establish if this is an existing Contact and if not, create one from data captured, then create the phone call record against the selected or created Contact. You can run a dialog like this from a link on a dashboard for example, you don't need to navigate to users screen to do it.
- Gareth Tucker has written several articles on his blog at http://gtcrm.wordpress.com about contact centre automation, including some interesting ideas (with free downloadable examples) about using JScript on the phone call form to capture contact details and create a linked Contact record on the fly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the business process could be improved. Ideally your solution would be to change your dialog process so that it runs against the customer (`contact`?) entity, i.e. when your customer calls up, users find that record and run your dialog instead of creating a phone call activity then running the dialog.

That said, if I understand your question correctly, you are using the dialog perhaps to assist the user in finding the customer's details. Is this true? I don't understand how this would work so you may need to provide us with some extra information here.

If the underlying issue is that the user can't find the customer, it sounds like you need to provide more search fields for the user in the customer view...

Comment: What you said about running the dialog against the customer (contact entity) is indeed a logical choice. I didn't even think about it. If I would be the user I would do it in that way but I know it may be little confusing for end users though. I know when there's an incoming call they will press the phone call button for sure.

I was thinking if there's no other choice I could change the function of the "create a phone call" button in the ribbon? But I would avoid that because basically I have a same issue with all activity types.

Comment: You asked how it works. I have created a "fill" button into the form. It will launch the dialog. The dialog first asks to choose the contact information. Then based on that value it will show all buildings or apartments in which the contact is related to and asks to choose one. Then finally it asks to choose how the contact is related to that facility (tenant, owner, service company, etc.) It will show only the roles that are equivalent when taking into consideration values chosen earlier. I used connections for building up these relations. Then finally the dialog would fill the form.